# node.js and express: how to join a socket.io room/channel based on URL?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a fairly simple boardgame app using socket.io to synchronize moves between players. Currently, clients get directed to a login page where they can either create a new game with a name that becomes the identifer for a socket.io room, or join an existing game. This all works fairly well, but I'd like to present game creators with a URL to send to their friends that would bypass the login and take them directly to the game, something like
http://myttgame.com/games/MyAwesomeGame .

I'm using node and express on the server end. I know how to parse the URL using an express route like "/games/:channel", but then I'm stuck. How can I tie the initial web request to a later incoming socket request?

If I were using PHP, I could inject the join command directly into the html page like

```
<body> ...

  <script>
  <?php
    if($channel)
      echo "socket.emit('join game','$channel');";
    else
      echo "showLoginForm();";
  ?>
  </script>
</body>
```

Is there a proper way to handle this type of thing using express, or failing that, some crude workaround like php injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to handle two different requests. Something like that:

```
app.get('/games/:channel', function(req, res) {
        res.render('board.ejs')
        // do emit and rest stuff
    });

app.get('/games', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('createboard.ejs')
        // do emit and rest stuff
    });

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect('/login');
    //or
    res.render('login.ejs');
}
```

The url without channel will redirect him to login page or render login page in case when he is not logged in. Board.ejs during initialization can do your socket.emit('join game','$channel').

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for.